# Using IDictionary with Json?

Tags: c#, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api, idictionary

how to get the friends list (below) into and out from a iDictionary?

Example

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "John Smith", 
      "id": "111"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Alice Smith", 
      "id": "222"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Mary Smith", 
      "id": "333"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?format=json&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=100003243976011"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to add System.web and System.Web.Extensions assembly reference in your application
2. Then try to use following code

> string jsonData = @"{   ""data"": [     {       ""name"": ""John Smith"",        ""id"": ""111""     },
>                                                             {       ""name"": ""Alice Smith"",       ""id"": ""222""     },
>                                                             {       ""name"": ""Mary Smith"",        ""id"": ""333""     }   ],
>                               ""paging"": {     ""next"": ""https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?format=json&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=100003243976011""   } }";

```
            JavaScriptSerializer seri = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var items = seri.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonData);
        // As data in JSON is array get it deserialize as ArrayList of Dictionary<string,object>
            var dataArray =  items["data"] as ArrayList;    
        // Each item in array list contain key value pair of name and id
            foreach (Dictionary<string,object> item in dataArray)
                {
        //Read Item
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> detailItem in item)
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine(detailItem.Key + " - " + detailItem.Value);
                    }
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
        // Read Item
                }
```